# How to restore Visual Studio 2013 RC Start Menu shortcuts?

Tags: shortcuts, visual-studio-2013

I had Visual Studio 2013 Preview installed. I uninstalled it. Then I installed Visual Studio 2013 RC but most of the Start Menu shortcuts are missing.

I tried repairing the installation but it did not create the icons.

Comment: Did you try fully uninstalling the RC and then reinstalling it?

Comment: Yes. I did. It didn't help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem.  After a short search I realized they changed the name of the shortcut folder from "Microsoft Visual Studio 2013" to just "Visual Studio 2013".

See the following for details:  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/802119/missing-vs2013-shortcut-after-install

Comment: Awesome, a forum to vent my nerd-rage on; why the heck could they not stick with their own freaking convention?! I've got everything else MS nicely grouped together (Expression, Lync, Network Monitor, Office, Silverlight, SQL Server, Sync, Team Foundation Power Tools, VS2005, VS2008, VS2010, VS2012). Seriously... what a daft decision! .../endrant

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

Many icons in the start menu and some others in the taskbar went missing after the installation of Visual Studio Express 2013 for Desktop.

I went to the display options (Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display) and change the display from 100% to 150% and the icons reappeared. I reverted to 100% and the icons were still there.