# How should I uninstall Visual Studio Ultimate 2013?

Tags: windows-8.1, uninstall, visual-studio-2013

I want to uninstall Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 and install the Community edition. However, I am unable to due so since the setup blocks me saying that Ultimate 2013 is installed, despite me having removed Visual Studio Ultimate 2013. I have tried the following:

Uninstalling VSU2013 using the Add and Remove Features in the Control    Panel. It was taking way too long (I waited for 6 hours, so I went       ahead and used IOBitUninstaller to remove it.     I then manually    deleted the folders from Program Files and Program    Files(x86).        I tried another uninstaller software, Revo.       I downloaded a    Registry Cleaner software and let it do its work.       I manually    deleted the Registry files associated with VSU2013.

After all this, I still get the error. I have spent almost the whole day trying to solve this problem. Could someone please suggest a solution?

Update:

I have uninstalled Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 and installed Visual Studio Professional 2013. It shows up in Add or Remove Programs but there is no desktop shortcut nor does it show up in the Installed Apps in the Start Menu (Windows 8.1). Does anyone know where the launch file might be located?

Comment: And you do a repair instead of uninstall, then try to uninstall again?

Comment: I am past that stage. VSU2013 does not appear in the Control Panel or anywhere else. There seems to be no remnants of VSU2013 on my PC, yet I still get that error.

Comment: I'll say this much, the Windows installer puts tons of registry entries when installing, especially big pieces of software like VS.  I would try to reinstall and then uninstall.

Comment: Will let you know if it works.

Comment: Update Question: MS broke away from their naming convention with VS2013 on the Start Menu... look in the "V" group (for Visual), not in "M" (for Microsoft)... http://superuser.com/questions/648272/how-to-restore-visual-studio-2013-rc-start-menu-shortcuts

Answer (score 1):

If you axed the uninstall process before completion, then used a 3rd party tool to pull it out of the add/remove list and manually deleted a couple folders, then you have NOT completely removed it (as evidenced by your problems installing VSCE).

Reinstall VSU2013, then uninstall it again properly (via Add/remove programs), then install VSCE.

Comment: Am trying your suggestion. Hope it works.

Comment: Please check my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small Plugin type software called Unlocker. Install that and delete the installed directory of whatever you want to delete. Also, Before doing that close the processes via Task Manager which you think that are linked with the application you want to uninstall. And then Uninstall in any way you explained in your question. It will work.
You are not able to uninstall as it is a heavy application and so many processes are in memory, Without closing them you can't uninstall.